# Highcharts bar with negative stack: how to show different tooltip for left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

i am using highcharts bar with negative stack, problem is when i hover over the left side of the chart that is in red color it shows the correct disease name that is "TB Suspect" but when i hover over the blue bar it shows the same "TB Suspect" disease which is wrong, it should show "Otitis Media"
same problem for all other diseases

[image: bar with negative stack]

Here is the code

```
<script>
 $(function () {
    if($('#disease-bar').length > 0){
    // Age categories 
    var categories_c = [<?=$comm_disease_title?$comm_disease_title:0;?>];
    var categories_nc = [<?=$non_comm_disease_title?$non_comm_disease_title:0;?>];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#disease-bar').highcharts({
            colors: ['#dd4c39', '#00a9e9', '#c61a7e', '#bd8030', '#949293', '#075290', '#7db6ed', '#009451', '#c84433'],
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                backgroundColor: null
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Top Five Communicable & Non-communicable Diseases'
            },

            xAxis: [{
                categories: categories_c,
                reversed: false,
                crosshair: true,
                labels: {
                    step: 1
                }
            }, { // mirror axis on right side
                opposite: true,  
                reversed: false,
                categories: categories_nc,
                linkedTo: 0,
                labels: {
                    step: 1
                }
            }],
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                   var s = Math.abs(this.value);

                   if (s.toFixed(0) >= 1000000) {
                        return s.toFixed(0) / 1000000 + 'M';
                    } else {
                        return s.toFixed(0) / 1000 + 'K';
                    }

                }
            }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    //point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            //alert(this.name);return;
                            if(this.name=="Communicable"){
                                var url = 'disease.php<?=$next_url;?>&module=1';
                                }
                            else {
                                var url = 'disease.php<?=$next_url;?>&module=2'; 
                                }
                                //alert(url);
                            location.href = url;
                        }
                        ,legendItemClick: function (event) { 
                            //console.log(event.target.visible);
                            if(event.target.name=='Communicable'){
                                if(event.target.visible){this.chart.xAxis[0].update({
                          labels: {
                            enabled: false
                          }
                        });}
                                else {this.chart.xAxis[0].update({
                          labels: {
                            enabled: true
                          }
                        });} 


                        }


                            else {
                                if(event.target.visible){this.chart.xAxis[1].update({
                          labels: {
                            enabled: false
                          }
                        });}
                                else {this.chart.xAxis[1].update({
                          labels: {
                            enabled: true
                          }
                        });} 


                        }
                            //console.log(event.target.name);
                       //console.log(this.chart.xAxis[0]);


                    }

                    }
               // }
                }
            },

            tooltip: {{

                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
                        'Diseases: <b>' + Math.abs(this.point.y) +'</b>'; 
                } 
            },

 exporting: {
            //enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
            series: [{
                name: 'Communicable', 
                data: [<?=$comm_disease_value?$comm_disease_value:0;?>]
            }, {
                name: 'Non-communicable',
                data: [<?=$non_comm_disease_value?$non_comm_disease_value:0;?>]
            }]
        });
    });
    }
});
 </script>
```

Here is the tooltip code which i am using

```
tooltip: {{

                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
                        'Diseases: <b>' + Math.abs(this.point.y) +'</b>'; 
                } 
            },
```

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hamza9/h1nrn9nu/

Comment: can you add fiddle example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the correct category from the formatter:

```
formatter: function() {
    var subCategoryLabel = this.series.chart.xAxis[this.series._i]
                               .categories[this.point.index];
    return '<b>' + subCategoryLabel + '</b><br/>' +
           'Diseases: <b>' + Math.abs(this.point.y) + '</b>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify series data as array of object, where`dd` is respective categories name and `y` is the value

```
 series: [{
    name: 'Communicable',
    data: [{y:-1489599,dd:'Acute (Upper) Respiratory Infections'}, {y:-256548,dd:'Scabies'}, {y:-157531,dd:'Diarrhoea / Dysentery < 5 yrs'}, {y:-148696,dd:'Diarrhoea / Dysentery > 5 yrs'}, {y:-86283,dd:'Worm Infestations'}]
      //url: 'disease.php?frequency=m&year=2017&month=1&quarter=&fatype=&disease_cat=comm'
  }, {
    name: 'Non-communicable',
    data: [{y:399786,dd:'Fever due to other causes'}, {y:247500,dd:'Peptic Ulcer Diseases'}, {y:196653,dd:'Hypertension'}, {y:176866,dd:'Dental Caries'}, {y:169514,dd:'Diabetes Mellitus'}]
      //url: 'disease.php?frequency=m&year=2017&month=1&quarter=&fatype=&disease_cat=noncomm'
  }]
```

In your tooltip you can access it via the "point" attribute of the object passed in:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + this.point.dd + '</b><br/>' +
        'Diseases: <b>' + Math.abs(this.point.y) + '</b>';
    }
  },
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/9nw6cz41/2/) demo

Answer (score 1):

Simply get rid of the `linkedTo` property from the second xAxis and link 'Non-Communicable' series to `1` xAxis.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cbar%3E.xAxis

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/yqe0kunn/